# Pass variable between two different html file

Tags: php, html

This question may be common question. But this is my exact problem. I am not going to write my code, but explain the scenario.

I have 2 html files to get value from user and 1 php file to process request from 2 html files through XHR.

first html file have person information (like name and email etc..) and following to second html to start another input data.

I save this information in the text file using person name. I could create text file using XHR request to php from first html.

How do I take the filename again which i created in the person name to store the data from second html.

I could not store the filename in any variable because each XHR return is happening individually. So I can't pass choose the filename.

Any idea how do i tackle this?

Comment: html isn't programmable, there are no "variables" in html. you need to show what these files look like, what you're trying to extract, and what the result should look like... because right now the description makes no sense.

Comment: Without seeing code, some of the ways to pass information between pages are session variables, cookies, querystrings, form data - like hidden fields (post or get), databases, and some local storage types.

Answer (score 2):

I would use PHP session mechanism with `session_start();` and save variable on session like this `$_SESSION['file_name']=fileName;` take closer look here [PHP tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

As said by Marc B, there are no variables in HTML, or a way to store variables and transfer them to another HTML page. You can only use cookies to store and transfer data from one HTML page to the other. Cookies can be handled with PHP Sessions.

You can check a small tutorial on [how to create cookies Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)